# highcharts are not displayed in jquery ui tabs with ie8

Tags: php, internet-explorer-8, highcharts, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm actually using jquery-ui tabs. I need to put in each tab some charts from HighCharts library. It works fine on firefox, but the problem is on IE8. Indeed, charts are not displayed at all, and it seems to crash when generating charts.
I'm sorry i can't give you an url example.

Here is the code of one chart :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container1',
        borderColor: '#CCCCCC',
        borderWidth: 2,
        type: 'line',
        height : ".$height.",
        width : ".$width.",
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'exemple'
    },      
    subtitle: {
        text: 'subtitle'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['" . implode("', '", $xValues) . "'],
                    type:'datetime',
                    maxZoom: 1
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'ordonnees'
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        type : 'image/png',
        scale: 2

    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true 
                },
        marker:{
            enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    series: [";
        $d = "";
        foreach($data as $leg => $val)
        {
            $s =  implode(', ', $val);
            $d .= "{ name: '$leg',
            data: [" . $s . "] }, ";
        }
        $sortie .= $d;
        $sortie .= "]
    });
});
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: are you getting any javascript errors in console?

Comment: No. But I think i've founded the problem. When i add values manually it works, so it's probably because of a last comma as i've ever seen in other forums. I'll try to fix this then i'll come back here to tell you.

Comment: So i've founded the solution. It's indeed the last comma for my series values. So i just added a condition and if it's the last line of my table, i don't print comma. And it works.

Thank you

Comment: no problem. I would suggest using json_encode rather than a foreach loop

Comment: why do you suggest that ?
and how to apply it in this ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a php array for the data. It will take an array and return a valid json representation. So you won't have to worry about things like trailing commas.

Comment: The problem was with extra comma, but also you can check howto use json_encode() in our article http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$data-from-sql